# KDE: Meta+Ctrl+Alt = always on top (Modifier only shortcut) - I have read that you can add to ~/.config/kwinrc

Tags: keyboard, kubuntu, shortcut-keys, kde

In KDE I am not able to add keyboard shortcuts that just use modifiers in the settings GUI, however I have read that you can add to `~/.config/kwinrc` something like..

```
[ModifierOnlyShorcuts]
Alt=
Control=
Meta=org.kde.krunner,/App,,display
Shift=org.kde.plasmashell,/PlasmaShell,org.kde.PlasmaShell,activateLauncherMenu
```

..to make a shortcut with just modifiers, however it seems as if this only works for a single key, does anyone know how I can make this work for <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the link for "I have read that you can add to ~/.config/kwinrc something like..". Also, do you want to assign the combination of Ctrl+Meta+Alt to some KWin action? What is your reasoning for that? Just curious!

Comment: Done. Yes I want to assign it to keep the current window always on top which in KDE is called "keep window above others"

Comment: I'm sorry I wasn't clear! I was asking for the source that you read.